# Cleaning Latitudes and Longitudes Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file containing Latitudes, longitudes and Date but `lat` and `long` contains some special characters like comma(,) and (\t) etc.

CSV file look like this:

```
| lat         | long        | date       |
| 30.970695,  | 72.482265   | 05/23/2015 | 
| 30.284493\t | 73.106275   | 07/01/2015 |
| 30.311023\t | 73.153053   | 07/01/2015 |
| 30.289273`  | 73.067512   | 07/02/2015 |
| 30.309319\t | 73.068774   | 07/03/2015 |
```

The data types are:

```
 lat   object 
 long  object 
 date  object 

dtype: object
```

I tried to remove special characters from latitude and longitude

```
df['lat'] = df['lat'].str.replace(r'[^\d.-]', '', regex=True)
df['long'] = df['long'].str.replace(r'[^\d.-]', '', regex=True)
```

I want to convert lat longs into float but I noticed this result after removing special charachters.

| index | lat | long | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5514 | 30.30116873.070213 | 30.30116873.070213 | 12/28/2015 |

lat and long values of row `5514` get merged.

Why am I getting this behavior? How do I solve this?
I am new with spatiotemporal data any recommendations and help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"CSV file look like this"_ is clearly nonsense because you have presented a table, not CSV.  Present your CSV data here as plain text.

Comment: I'm not allowed to publicly disclose complete data here but I will convert it into Plain text

Comment: You don't need complete data, just the fragment you posted in plain text.  How can removing commas from _comna separated values_ (CSV) possibly make any sense for in any case?

Comment: Then How can I convert values into float with commas.

Comment: Is it just row 5514 in which this happens? Because that is how your question reads.  But that is not the row you presented earlier.  My point is we need to see the actual input data and the resulting output for _at least_ one example row.  Also "_special characters like_" is not very specific.  In CSV commas are delimiters and should not be removed - it is not CSV without the commas, clearly!

Comment: That is why we need to see the plain-text source data.  Some locales use a comma as a decimal point - that is problematic for CSV, so I suspect your data is not CSV.  Perhaps TSV (tab separated).  If you have quote-delimited strings containing commas, then they are not delimiters, but you will need more than just a regular expression to process that.  This conversation is pointless untill we can see the raw data, because it is clearly not regular CSV as you state.

Comment: ... as I said (now you have edited it), that is _not_ CSV. Is that truly what your input looks like? Are those `\t` literal or have you tried to represent TAB characters in the original data?

Comment: My input is as same as provided in plain text

Comment: I'm not sure it is csv or tsv, I get this file in csv format. But if it is not then what steps should I take to handle this data?

Comment: Which is why you needed to present the raw date - because it is not what you stated it's format to be.  You should present the output in plain text also (I said that already, so it is not clear why you did not fix that). The code is generating undesired output, we need to see the actual output, not something post-processed into a table.

Comment: It is not an issue of _"spatiotemporal"_ data.  Your data has clearly been processed or scraped from somewhere by some imperfect method that has included some junk.

Comment: Did you try converting to floating point without removing the junk?  Given its position at the end of the numeric string, that will work, you just need to extract the string between `|` delimiters.

Comment: _"I get this file in csv format."_ havoing a .csv extension doe snot make it CSV format - that is just misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the characters that you don't want, it is perhaps easier to extract the ones that you *do* want. Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and chain [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to set the `dtype` to float afterwards. For the regex pattern used below, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/McGnLz/1).

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

# adding a "-" sign to the last value in `df['Lat']`
s = """lat|long|date
30.970695,|72.482265|05/23/2015
30.284493\t|73.106275|07/01/2015
30.311023\t|73.153053|07/01/2015
30.289273`|73.067512|07/02/2015
-30.309319\t|73.068774|07/03/2015
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="|", dtype=str)
```

**Code**

```
df[['lat','long']] = (df[['lat','long']]
                      .apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('(-?\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
                             .astype(float)
                             )
                      )

df

         lat       long        date
0  30.970695  72.482265  05/23/2015
1  30.284493  73.106275  07/01/2015
2  30.311023  73.153053  07/01/2015
3  30.289273  73.067512  07/02/2015
4 -30.309319  73.068774  07/03/2015
```

Answer (score -1):

After removing the special characters, you can convert the latitude and longitude values to float types using the pd.to_numeric() function, like this:

```py
df['lat'] = pd.to_numeric(df['lat'])
df['long'] = pd.to_numeric(df['long'])
```